# Add record from field information

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Data Frame in Python that contains names of actors and the movies in which they participated.

Something like that:

```
Name     Films

Adam     tt2488496,tt7653254,tt7653254,tt2488496
Jhon     tt1596363,tt1386588,tt6266538
Juan     tt7653254,tt2488496
```

I need to separate the actors for each movie they participated in.

just like that:

```
Name     Films

Adam     tt2488496
Adam     tt7653254
Adam     tt7653254
Adam     tt2488496
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Use `df.assign(Films=df['Films'].str.split(',')).explode('Films')`

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it is by using pandas [melt function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) as shown below:

```
# split the films column to many columns
df2 = df['films'].str.split(expand = True)
```

now df2 is

```
      0             1         2            3
0   tt2488496   tt7653254   tt7653254   tt2488496
1   tt1596363   tt1386588   tt6266538   None
2   tt7653254   tt2488496   None        None
```

Join those split columns with Names column

```
df3= pd.concat([df['Names'], df2], axis = 1)

   Names          0            1            2        3
0   Adam    tt2488496   tt7653254   tt7653254   tt2488496
1   John    tt1596363   tt1386588   tt6266538   None
2   John    tt7653254   tt2488496   None        None
```

Use pandas melt to unpivot and drop unnecessary columns and Nans'

```
final_result = pd.melt(df3, id_vars = ['Names'], value_vars = list(df2.columns)).drop(columns = ['variable']).dropna()
```

which is

```
   Names      value
0  Adam  tt2488496
1  John  tt1596363
2  John  tt7653254
3  Adam  tt7653254
4  John  tt1386588
5  John  tt2488496
6  Adam  tt7653254
7  John  tt6266538
9  Adam  tt2488496
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.Films.str.split(',').tolist(), index=df.Name).stack().reset_index()[['Name',0]]
df.columns = ['Name', 'Films']

   Name      Films
0  Adam  tt2488496
1  Adam  tt7653254
2  Adam  tt7653254
3  Adam  tt2488496
4  Jhon  tt1596363
5  Jhon  tt1386588
6  Jhon  tt6266538
7  Juan  tt7653254
8  Juan  tt2488496
```